# Enumerate all outgoing Queues in MSMQ, C#

Tags: c#, msmq

Using C# and .NET 3.5, how can I get a listing of all outgoing queues in MSMQ? I found [this article about it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MSMQ.aspx) but as you can see below I do not have the COM entry for `Microsoft Message Queue 3.0 Object Library`...

[image: I accidentally the Microsoft Message Queue 3.0 Object Library]

So how can I get the current outgoing queue listing? I figured there must be a way since I can see them in `Computer Management`...

[image: Computer Management + MSMQ]

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two good places to start I think would be these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I'll see if I can work up some code.

---

Perhaps not, those look old, still looking.

---

Heres some WScript that will show them to you, still looking for .Net code:

```
Dim Locator
Set Locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Dim objs
Set Service = Locator.ConnectServer(".", "root\cimv2")
Set objs = Service.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue")
For Each object In objs
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & object.Name
Next
```

---

```
using System.Management;
namespace TestMSMQStuff
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Management.SelectQuery q = new SelectQuery("Select * From Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue");
            ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);
            foreach (var r in s.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.Properties["Name"].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like all the outgoing queues start with "os:"

Need to references System.Management and System.Management.Instrumentation

Comment: The issue I had with those (at least as far as I could tell) was that I had to add the COM reference. However, in my Visual Studio 2008 there is no entry for the `Microsoft Message Queue 3.0 Object Library`. I am not sure how to correct this state, or how to work around it. But yes, those two articles reference similar methods I had listed in the [linked article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MSMQ.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to Interop this with C#? If there is how would I do it?

Comment: I see your code update, I'll be trying it out and reporting back!

Comment: ...ok well that got me a list of format names I needed. That's a great start. However, can you explain the "science" of your code snippet to me? I've been trying to get a solution for this, and I'd like to know the reasoning about your code. I'd be more than happy to mark your answer correct after that.

Comment: Alright this makes sense now that I have learned more about WMI. Thank you for this awesome answer :)

Comment: Is there no way to do this using the C# MSMQ library? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Messaging.MessageQueue_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BenjaminSussman from what I can find it's still either COM or WMI to get at the outgoing queues