# Get MSMQ Queues using WMI and C#

Tags: c#, wmi, msmq

I found the basic answer to my question here: [Enumerate all outgoing Queues in MSMQ, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191663/enumerate-all-outgoing-queues-in-msmq-c-sharp), however when I try to run the code posted in the answer it takes several seconds to several minutes before throwing an exception "Invalid Query".

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\"+Environment.MachineName+@"\root\cimv2");
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue");
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
   foreach (var queue in searcher.Get())
   {

   }
}
```

Stack Trace:
 at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at TestGetQueueSize.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\lindj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestGetQueueSize\TestGetQueueSize\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Can you provide any more exception details? Do you get a stack trace? When do you get the exception, when calling `searcher.get()`?

Comment: Yes I get the exception when calling searcher.Get(), there weren't any more details in the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the performance counters for MSMQ are not installed, I've opened a new question to deal with this problem: [MSMQ WMI Query Failing Due to Missing Performance Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945713/msmq-wmi-query-failing-due-to-missing-performance-counters)