# MSMQ WMI Query Failing Due to Missing Performance Counters

Tags: powershell, wmi, msmq

When trying to execute the following query from powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue"
```

I receive the error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  -query "Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue"
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I have diagnosed this to the performance counters for MSMQ missing, when I look in the registry under SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSMQ\ I do not see a Performance key.

I found the following Microsoft KB on reloading the performance counters but the steps in it do not work http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;936493. When I run "Unlodctr MSMQ" I get the error:

```
Unable to open driver SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSMQ\Performance. Status: 2
```

Then when I run "Lodctr Mqperf.ini" I get:

```
Unable to find initialization file Mqperf.ini
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to reinitialize my MSMQ performance counters?

Comment: Try this [How to repair MSMQ Performance Counters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/05/24/how-to-repair-the-msmq-performance-counters.aspx)

Comment: That's where I found the KB article, unless I'm misreading it it has no new information